# Replace $ with \$ in string for Dart consumption (not raw)

Tags: dart, flutter

This seems like an easy question, but I can't figure it out.

I have a string in a JSON object that is generated from another language which contains escape characters and dollar signs (which should be interpreted as dollar signs).  When I use this string in Dart, it complains about the $ because it thinks it is a variable.  Adding the r in front of the string to interpret the string as raw is not sufficient because then it doesn't interpret any of the other escape characters.

For example, given the following string:

```
line 1 costs $250 and\nline 2 costs $300
```

I need to convert it to this so that I can work with it in Dart:

```
line 1 costs \$250 and\nline 2 costs \$300
```

I also want to create a test for this condition for my converter.

I have tried the following without luck:

```
String s2 = s1.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\$'),r'\$');
```

and for the test:

```
expect(s1, contains('\$'));
expect(s2, contains('\\\$'));
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you loading the string? If it's defined in the source file, wouldn't it be easier to just replace the dollar signs directly in the editor?

Comment: @ViniciusPinto, It's loaded as legacy data from any number of users through a JSON file.  That's why I need a generic solution.  Thanks.

Comment: and how are you loading the JSON? AFAIK interpolation is only for strings declared in the source (if I use `jsonDecode()` from dart:convert, for example, it doesn't care about $ in the string).

Comment: @ViniciusPinto, Thanks for pointing me down the right path.  I was mocking some data and had just copy/pasted the json data and had to manually change $ to \$, but now I see that I will not have that problem with the real data when I jsonDecode() it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @ViniciusPinto, using `jsonDecode()` avoids this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the string is from JSON then Dart does no interpolation.

Interpolation works only with strings in Dart source code. No need to replace `$` in your case.